# Stored procedure variable null vs equal to null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a difference between

```
 create procedure usp_UpdateEmployee
 @Name varchar(50) null,
 @DOB datetime null
```

and

```
 create procedure usp_UpdateEmployee
 @Name varchar(50) = null,
 @DOB datetime = null
```

If so, can you please let me know the difference when calling these stored procedures and which one to use when?

Answer (score 0):

The first denotes that the parameter can be `NULL`. For most procedures defining this doesn't add anything as only natively compiled procedures support `NOT NULL` parameters; in your example it is therefore very likely that the `NULL` is superfluous.

The latter is the `DEFAULT` value for the parameter. If the parameter is omitted then the `DEFAULT` value is used, or you can explicitly define the `DEFAULT` value be used:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @i int NULL = NULL AS
--CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @i int = NULL AS --This is effectively identical syntax
BEGIN
    SELECT @i;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.SomeProc; --Returns NULL

EXEC dbo.SomeProc @i = DEFAULT;

EXEC dbo.SomeProc DEFAULT; --As @i is the first ordinal parameter


GO

DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc;
```

The default value doesn't have to be `NULL`; it can be what ever you like/need. Note that the default value must be a literal, you can't use an expression to define the default value. `CREATE PROC dbo.OtherProc @d date = GETDATE()` would not work, for example.

Comment: Put more clearly, if you don't supply `= NULL` then the parameter *must* be specified even if it is passed as null